# ASP.NET Core 3.0 JSON Serialisation Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core

I am converting an ASP.NET Web API to ASP.NET Core API.

This is my class, the same code works in the WEB API.

```
public class TotalEquipments
{
    public string Totalresults { get; set; }
    public Equipment Equipment;
}

public class Equipment
{
    public string CardName { get; set; }
    public string CardCode { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string Serialno { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Expected OutPut:

```
[{"Equipment":{"CardName":"PT Syspex Kemasindo","CardCode":"C-USD-0032","ItemCode":"V0437-MH009-2002","ItemName":"Smipack Shrink Machine (Manual L Sealer), Model: S560","serialno":"00004183","status":"Active"},"totalresults":"1719"},{"Equipment":{"CardName":"PT Syspex Kemasindo","CardCode":"C-USD-0032","ItemCode":"V0402-MH010-0001","ItemName":"Automatic Strapping Machine, Model: TZ 700 (850x600)","serialno":"014437","status":"Active"},"totalresults":"1719"}]
```

Output i am getting:

```
[{"Totalresults":"1719"},{"Totalresults":"1719"}]
```

Comment: Add getter and setters for th Equipment property on TotalEquipments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON serialiser in .NET Core 3 (the objects in the `System.Text.Json` namespace) does not serialise [fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields), only [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties). So you just need to fix your model:

```
public class TotalEquipments
{
    public string Totalresults { get; set; }
    public Equipment Equipment { get; set; } // <--- This
}
```